# Preserving array for only one loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to clear my preserved array after one loop.

I am moving an array of sheet names to a new workbook.

In the next loop I have an error as the worksheets are no longer there. I think that is why I get an error. The first workbook saves so the error occurs on second loop.

```vb
Sub Select_tabs()

Dim sheetArray() As String
Dim FarmName As Range
Dim Farm As Range
Dim WBname As Variant
Dim FileName As Range
Dim Name As Range

Set FarmName = Sheets("File ref").Range("Farms")
Set FileName = Sheets("File ref").Range("FileName")

For Each Name In FileName

    For Each Farm In FarmName

        If (Farm.Offset(, 1)) = Name.Value Then
            ReDim Preserve sheetArray(0 To i)
            sheetArray(i) = Farm.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
        
    Next Farm
    Sheets(sheetArray).Select
    Sheets(sheetArray).Move
    WBname = "file location\By Farm Verification - " & Name.Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs WBname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next Name
End Sub
```

Comment: `Erase sheetArray`

Comment: sorry not sure i understand. Remove the array all together?

Comment: the [Erase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/erase-statement) Statement clears the dynamic array, resetting it back to an empty array (no elements) and frees the memory reserved by the array. You can still reuse the variable name and rebuild a new array. So you just need to include `Erase` at the top of the loop to ensure the array is cleared before each new loop.

Comment: You might want to clear "i" as well

Comment: Thanks, i understand now. I'm still getting the error at the same point on the second loop.

Comment: Thank you that has solved it.